# Is there a term to refer to movies in which one or more actors died during production period and stand-ins were used?

Tags: terminology, cinema

The best I can think of is "movie with late actors", but it sounds weird and not very concise. I wonder if there's a technical term to refer to that type of movies.

Comment: Do you know of one in any language?

Comment: "Movie with late actors" sounds weird also because "late actors" cannot possibly act. In any case, that expression does not tell that the actors died while the movie was in progress, they could have died much later even (they are "late actors" at the time of writing, not making the movie).

Comment: A posthumous movie? I don't know if it makes any sense, but for other works of art this term is very much preferable.

Comment: Sounds like a disaster movie to me.

Comment: @WS2 [The Crow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Crow_%281994_film%29) is probably one of the most famous and extreme examples, where the actor Brandon Lee (the son of Bruce Lee) was shot dead with a prop gun during filming.

Comment: I don't know if there exists such a word , even if it does, it would mainly be known to people in Film Industry. I tried to google on F&F 7 but couldn't find anything.

Comment: The BBC radio soap, *The Archers* which has taken the 7.00 to 7.15pm slot on Radio 4 (formerly Home Service), every evening (except Sat), for the last 64 years  has an ongoing cast of characters. From time to time someone dies, retires, reneges on it, or gets fired. Sometimes the character dies with the actor. Sometimes a new person takes over and affects the voice of the previous incumbent. I know of no expression which describes the process of one actor taking up a part previously played by another. Nor have I ever been aware of a need for such a word to be coined.

Comment: The most infamous case of using a stand-in was _Plan 9 From Outer Space_ (also notorious as one of the worst movies ever made). Bela Lugosi died during the filming, and the director got his wife's chiropractor to fill in, despite being noticeably taller and bearing no resemblance (I think he covered his face with his vampire cape in all his scenes). But these days, they'll usually rewrite the script to work around the actor's death.

Comment: It happened in the Gladiators when the British hell-raiser, boozer & sometime actor Oliver Reed croaked mid-way through the making of the movie. The movie makers used outtakes and computer wizardry to piece together Ollie's character on screen to give some semblance of continuity to the plot and belief in the composite character on screen. In Sparticus it was discovered that parts of the sound track on the film negative had degraded & the great Welsh actor (wonderful mimic) Anthony Hopkins was drafted in to re-record/dub the late Laurence Oliver's voice. There must be a technical word for it

Answer (score -1):

The deceased actor is *recast* with a new actor, example sentence [according to MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/recast):

> The director recast some of the actors in the play.

Example from [OLD](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/recast):

> ‘Picture The Bad News Bears and the Mighty Ducks recast with actors from Crouching Tiger, Hidden Dragon and Game of Death.’

The term is also used on the [Wikipedia page: List of television actors who died during production](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_television_actors_who_died_during_production):

> "In other cases, the show may recast the part with another actor."

To indicate the recast was due to the previous actor's dying, you might say:

> Movies in which several actors had to be recast with new actors, because they are no longer with us

Or ever shorter:

> Movies in which several actors had to be recast because they are no longer with us